# Get user's profile using DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

Either i use my gmail or yahoo id as OpenID. I need the server to return me Fullname, Gender and Age, after authentication. Is any one having solution to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think either Google or Yahoo! will disclose the user's gender or age.  You can very likely get their full name, however.

This page's documentation should answer your question.  http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/the-axfetchassregtransform-behavior/